# Which scriptures say that "Durga Devi is ignorant about Spiritual Life"?

Tags: scripture, durga

As per the question : [What is the source of "ārādhanānāṁ sarveṣāṁ viṣṇor ārādhanaṁ param" (of all methods of worship, Viṣṇu worship is the topmost)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34753/what-is-the-source-of-%c4%81r%c4%81dhan%c4%81n%c4%81%e1%b9%81-sarve%e1%b9%a3%c4%81%e1%b9%81-vi%e1%b9%a3%e1%b9%87or-%c4%81r%c4%81dhana%e1%b9%81-param-of-all-meth)  His Holiness Srila Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada says

> **Durgā-devī** is in charge of this material world. It is called durga, durga, just like fort. And the superintendent of this fort is Durgā. You cannot go out of this fort; you are imprisoned. Such Durgā-devī, who is so powerful energy—she can create, annihilate, maintain, sṛṣṭi-sthiti-pralaya-sādhana—she is always sitting by the side of her husband, Lord Śiva, and questioning about spiritual enquiries. Just see. **Such powerful deity is also ignorant about spiritual life.** **So** the husband, Lord Śiva, is Vaiṣṇava, and **she's always asking, and sitting down underneath a bael tree.** She can create so many universes, but for her, no building; only underneath a tree.

As per the Devi-Sukta of the Vedas, Devi Herself is Para-Brahman.As per Sri Sri Devi-Mahatmya, She is the Primal Cause of the Universe and the Supreme Goddess.

Devi asks Lord Shiva different questions in the Tantras also, but there it is seen as Her grace so that the knowledge of the Supreme is revealed through Shiva.

Which scriptures support Srila Prabhupada's claim that 'Durga Devi is ignorant about spiritual life' and being 'always' seated 'under a bael tree'? Also, any light on who created that bael tree?

Comment: "His Holiness" please do not do this.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu His Holiness is a word used for the top positions of the sects

Comment: He is dead. So there is not much use for it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Gurus are never dead!

Comment: His body looks pretty dead to me!

Comment: You should probably add 'prabhupada' and 'identification-request' tags since you are asking for the source of Prabhupada's claim.

Comment: @sv. It has nothing to do with who told this. My question is whether this is mentioned in any scripture or not. I am not sure whether such a thing can exist at all in the scriptures, and so did not add identification request.Would be like requesting to identify a ghost:)